# What is the correct setting in Adobe Premiere CS6 for Nikon Video?

Tags: premiere, dslr, nikon

I have a Nikon D600 and when I set up a new project in Adobe Premiere CS6 there are many options available for Sequence Presets. I suppose this could be a subjective question, but what is the best preset for Nikon DSLR video? ARRI? Digital SLR, etc.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to set up a sequence with the right settings for your footage is to first import the video footage into your Premiere Pro project. Then right click on the clip in the media bin, and select "new sequence from clip." That will create a new sequence with settings that match your footage.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is going to be a format which matches the resolution, pixel pitch, frame rate and color format/color space of your original footage.  These settings can typically be changed based on the shooting mode you used on your camera, so there is not enough detail in your question to give a specific setting.  If you actually open up the footage file, it should show these details in the properties for the clip and you can choose a sequence preset accordingly.

Comment: Hi AJ, how do I view those properties before I import it into Premiere?

Comment: @fmz - I normally import it in to Premiere or After Effects and then adjust my settings accordingly.  Depending on the format, simply right clicking the file and going to properties may give you the details you need, but it's usually a lot easier to just import it first and get to the details that way.